# Can't get rid of bottom padding on button

Tags: android

I have a button. It seems to have bottom padding I cannot get rid of:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Foo"/>
```

In the resource editor, I can click the button, and you see the padding below the bottom edge of the button there. This seems to block me from properly centering the button vertically in a parent RelativeLayout.

[image]

I tried setting padding=0dip and layout_margin=0dip, no effect. That bottom padding persists.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The padding is in the 9-patch of the buttons themselves.

I'd advise against trying to compensate because these graphics resources can change without notice. You'd be better off [building your own 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) or editing the existing one to remove the padding.

Answer (score 3):

setting **android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"** for the button worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 2):

**I am late to answer this but thought to share if someone come across similar use case( `Removing all the inner and outer padding in Button` )**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:minHeight="-2dp"
android:minWidth="-2dp"
android:text="TextView"
android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmn really strange. Never noticed that. Probably because u usally *want* a little space around your buttons.

Also tried margin/padding=0dp and did in fact not work.

You could set android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp" however :).