# Align TextView, Button, EditText

Tags: android, alignment

How can i align my TextView and Button to left and EditText and Button to right? Here is the form that contains unaligned items.

[image]

My xml file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/PlateEntryRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RequestButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PlateEdit"
        android:text="@string/request" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PlateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/PlateEdit"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PlateEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/plate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PlateEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It looks pretty aligned to me. Could you be a bit more specific

Comment: look at "P" letter and left frame of button more detailly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put this to textview

```
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
```

But I suggest you check this question
[Can't get rid of bottom padding on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211774/cant-get-rid-of-bottom-padding-on-button)